# How to reduce noise from trash chute door closing?

Tags: doors, noise

I live in an apartment and unfortunately I live in a room right next to the trash chute room. I hear this loud clicking noise multiple times a day, including sometimes at night and it's starting to get really annoying. I know this can be solved very easily. But I have no idea how to fix this myself.

I uploaded some images on what the door looks like.

<sub>*Click any photo for full size*</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you're going to include an action shot of the door closing, you should also include the shutter speed of the camera. Otherwise there's no way to calculate the speed of the door.

Comment: The fix here is going to depend on the problem. Since you describe it as a "clicking noise", I'd bet it's not the door slamming shut, which would be more of a bang. Instead I'd suspect either the handle being actuated, the latch bolt hitting the strike plate, or the latch bolt extending into the closed lock position. The latch bolt noise is a very common problem, especially with steel doors which have steel frames. Is it possible to switch rooms?

Answer (score 1):

Since you rent this apartment don't try to adjust it yourself. If adjusted incorrectly the door can be a safety hazard if it closes too fast. Call the maintenance person or building super and ask them to check and adjust the automatic door closer. The closer can be adjusted to slow the rate the door closes which will make it quieter.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mikes's suggestion that the closing speed could be adjusted, I would like to add that with this type of door, there are little rubber bumpers on the door frame, which the door rests against when closed. One is visible in your fourth photo, next to the strike plate. If they are hardened (age, paint, etc.) or missing then that would also increase noise.

Consider having those bumpers replaced with fresh ones and ensure they are present everywhere they should be (look for small holes in the frame that should be plugged by them).